# Should the bracha for toiveling be repeated for subsequent immersions in a toiveling "session"?

Tags: halacha, blessing, tevilas-keilim-dipping, safek

If one is immersing multiple kelim in a toiveling "session" does the bracha need to be repeated for each immersion or can the bracha be said once at the start? Also, if one is toiveling a kli that is doubtful whether or not it requires immersion (such as pottery) must it be immersed with something certain in that particular immersion or is it enough that other items which we know must be toiveled were also toiveled in the session with the bracha?

Comment: Note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends, and go to your rabbi for practical guidance.

Comment: @msh210 Shuold these questions be split?

Comment: @DoubleAA, eh. Likely they're dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chaf-K](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108090419w-4%20dos%20and%20donts%20of%20tevilas%20keilim.pdf) says that the bracha applies to all kailim that the person had in mind when he siad the bracha.

> One who is being tovel more than one utensil should be careful not to
> talk between the first utensil and the second. 35
>
> One who is toveling keilim and new keilim are brought to be toveled
> which he did not intend to tovel  at the time he recited the beracha ,
> would need to recite a new beracha before toveling these utensils. 36
>
> 35 Tevilas Keilim 9:17, Vayitzvar Yosef 2:5:4:footnote 9.
>
> 36 Refer to Shulchan Aurch Y.D. 19:6

Of course if you have a particular question, CYLOR. [Tevilas Keilim Guidelines](http://www.star-k.org/articles/kosher-lists/1170/tevilas-keilim-guidelines/) implies that the bracha applies to the entire session. This is also the way that the instructions are given at the Agudath Israel of Baltimore kailim mikvah under the supervision of Rav Heinemann - who is the rav of the Star-K. As we see, the Jewish adult can tovel the first few items in a session (with a bracha) and then let a child or a nonJew tovel remaining items. A pot and cover can be toveled seperately.

> One wets one’s hands in the mikvah water, holds the vessel in the wet
> hand and says Baruch…Asher Kidshanu B’Mitzvosav V’Tzivanu Al Tevilas
> Keili (Keilim for multiple utensils) and immerses the vessel(s).
>
> The cover can be immersed separately if it is removable.
>
> Anyone may toivel keilim, including a small child or a non-Jew,
> however, a **Jewish adult** must be present to verify that it took place.
> The recitation of a brocha can only be done if a Jew does the
> immersion. Therefore, if many utensils are to be immersed with the
> help of a child or a non-Jew, the owner should first immerse a few
> vessels with a brocha and then the child or non-Jew can take over.

Comment: "The recitation of a brocha can only be done if a Jew does the immersion." I don't understand why the children aren't viewed as Jewish...

Comment: @DoubleAA The meaning is an adult Jew. A katan must be supervised by an adult.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. The child can say the blessing, but it says the owner should first before the child takes over.

Comment: Can a person speak out between celim? Why does the bracha then go on the other celim if there was a hefsek?

Comment: @Yehoshua See the Chaf K citation.